# Program terminates entering pass into textbox with webrunner

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

     //Maximize the Browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://google.com");

    WebElement signin = driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70"));
    signin.click();

    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    username.sendKeys("email@gmail.com");

    WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.id("next"));
    next.click();

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
    password.sendKeys("password");

    WebElement next1 = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
    next1.click();
```

My program terminates when it gets to the password entry screen.. it says

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)

However, I have tried ID element and Xpath element and they are both correct

:
(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you need to wait after next.click(); command. After clicking next button, your input filed is not loaded yet. So, wait for the element to get loaded and put text in it.

**Edit:**

You can use explicit wait for this. It's better way then Thread.sleep(). Specify a maximum time to wait for element. If the specified time elapsed before your element is visible then it will throw a exception.

**Code snippet:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); // waiting for maxiumum of 30 seconds

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Password")));
```

Comment: Ahh! After googleing for code to allow my program to wait, I found one and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops, I am late...  :)